# How to divide one row of numbers in more rows in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, large-files

Hi I have a large list of numbers 1 - 100.000 in one row range  1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, .....  100.000 I need to divide it from 1-500 row and next row from 501 to 1000, next 1001-1500, and so one. Can someone give me some instructions how to do this? I use Notepad++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use replaceAll with regex (Keyword: lookaround assertions)

- Find what: `(?<=[05]00),\s`
- Replace with: `\n`

In other words: replace all `,` with following whitespace character coming after `500` or `000` by a line break